# How to solve this issue 1292 Truncated incorrect date value

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need your help. I am trying to convert a text field (containing: '2017-11-16 14:06:49') into a date field.I get the warning: **1292 Truncated incorrect date value: '2017-11-16 14:06:49'**(. I have also tried with STR_TO_DATE statement . I have entered SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES' to avoid some configuration error, but the error remains.
This is my Query:

```
SET @t = (
        SELECT COUNT(ac.id) 
        FROM table1 ac 
        WHERE STR_TO_DATE(ac.created_on, '%Y-%m-%d') 
            BETWEEN (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
            AND LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND ac.date = DATE(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
    );
```

---

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT)?

Comment: How does the date format look like in `ac.created_on` column?

Comment: @forpas Thank you for your efforts. I created the table by this 
https://dbfiddle.uk/Ztdvqw3C

Comment: @FanoFN ac.created_on date format is (varchar declaration)

Comment: In your code there is a `date` column which does not exist in the fiddle. Also, I asked if you can reproduce your issue in the fiddle and not just post sample data not indicative of the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what MySQL version you're using but in the fiddle for MySQL v8, your data in `ac.created_on` is recognizable as `date` so, doing `STR_TO_DATE(ac.created_on, '%Y-%m-%d')` seems unnecessary. https://dbfiddle.uk/WhWgwdRi

Comment: But of course, doing `STR_TO_DATE(ac.created_on, '%Y-%m-%d')` will return meaningless date value as `NULL` , such as `2023-04-31` - whereby in our calendar, _31st April_ doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by changing your VARCHAR column to DATETIME:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` MODIFY COLUMN `created_on` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
```

It will use less space and, more importantly, be faster to process.

---

If your `created_on` varchar column contains a valid DATETIME value as indicated, then you can just use `DATE(ac.created_on)` but this will make your query [non-SARGable](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/12/the-two-ways-to-fix-non-sargable-queries/).

Instead you should use:

```
SET @t = (
        SELECT COUNT(ac.id) 
        FROM table1 ac 
        WHERE ac.created_on >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        AND ac.created_on < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
        AND ac.date = LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    );
```

If routinely querying by `created_on` there should be an index on the column.